# How to add cells if conditions are met

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a statement that I send to customers showing how much money they owe us. In the balance column, I need it to have a rolling total but can't seem to figure the formula out. Below is my current formula.[image]

=IF(AND(ISBLANK(I23),ISBLANK(K23)),"",IF(B23="retention",0,IF(B23="payment",OFFSET(M23,-1,0,1,1)+I23-K23,IF(NOT(OR(B23="retention",B23="payment")),OFFSET(M23,-1,0,1,1)+I23-K23,OFFSET(M23,-2,0,1,1)))))

In the last row, it should total that of 15,500 plus the charges amount(500) minus payments totaling 16,000.

Comment: is row 23 the first in which you place the formula?

Comment: row 24 is the first row with the formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=IF(AND(I23="",K23=""),"",IF(B23="retention",0,SUMIFS($I$23:$I23,$B$23:$B23,"<>retention")-SUM($K$23:$K23)))
```

Where 23 is the first row in which the formula is placed, then copied down.

[image]